# JQuery: nextUntil() - weird problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

I'm building a page that features a hierarchical tree-type structure. I've posted a simplified version of it at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5arx/Sx4qg/61/)

It mostly works as I'd like but for one thing - on clicking closed a Brand-level row I would like, as well as the town and shoe rows to contract (which they do), for the anchors on the Town rows to change their text to '+'.

I've attempted to do so with

```
$(this).parent().parent().nextUntil(".TRBrand", ".TownToggle").text("+");
```

but try as I might it won't play nicely.

Can anyone point me in the right direction ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several problems with your version:

1. The last `<a>` (for Reebok) had the wrong class : `TRTown` instead of `TownToggle`
2. Your `nextUntil(...)` for `TownToggle` was only stopping when it sees `.TRTown`, which means it hides too much when it is the last Town in the list and continues to hide the next brand as well. It should also stop on `.TRBrasnd`. You can specify both selectors by seperating them with a comma.
3. `a.toggleTown` was not targetted correctly when updating the text value to `+`

If I understand your requirements correctly, the following should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Sx4qg/69/

```
$('.BrandToggle').click(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var txt = t.text();
    var tr = t.closest("tr");
    if (txt == "+") {
        tr.nextUntil(".TRBrand", ".TRTown").show();
    } else {
        tr.nextUntil(".TRBrand", ".TRTown, .TRShoes").hide();
        tr.nextUntil(".TRBrand", ".TRTown").find("a.TownToggle").text("+");
    }
    t.text(txt == "+" ? "-" : "+");
});

$(".TownToggle").click(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    var txt = t.text();
    var tr = t.closest("tr");
    if (txt == "+") {
        tr.nextUntil(".TRBrand,.TRTown", ".TRShoes").show();
    } else {
        tr.nextUntil(".TRBrand,.TRTown", ".TRShoes").hide();
    }
    t.text(txt == "+" ? "-" : "+");
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much. It was the targeting of the `a.toggletown` that was the issue. I've never used `find` before - very useful.

The other errors crept in when I converted my real scenario (automobile sales figures) to sports shoes :-o

Answer (score 4):

Nested lists are better for tree like structures. You can see the js is easier to write with this markup:

http://jsfiddle.net/RANmK/1/

Comment: U got a little problem bro. In the non expanding divs

Comment: Thanks, looks great. Unfortunately I'm working on a pre-written page so will have to stick to the less-than-ideal HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().nextUntil(".TRBrand").find('.TownToggle').text("+");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sangdol/Sx4qg/64/

Answer (score 1):

Hope this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAHRd/) will help

```
$(this).parent().parent().nextUntil("tr:not(.TRTown, .TRBrand)", ".TownToggle").text("+");
```